# How do I implement a function to traverse a nested list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, nested-lists

Let's say we have a nested list that looks like this:

X = [ [ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0] ]

I want to traverse the list X and do the following:

- Make sure that there are only 3 nested list.
- Each nested list has 3 integers in them
- Only one of the nested lists contain a zero (0). For example, if the first nested list has a 0 in it then none of the nested list should have a 0.
- Make sure none of the nested lists contain an integer greater than 8.

So far I did this. But it is not working.

```
nested_lists([[Head|State]]) :-
  Head >= 0,
  Head =< 8,
  nested_lists(State).
```

Comment: Your one and only example has all the digits unique - if they need to be unique, please state that rule. It's nice to have several examples.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing in X is [1,2,3] so `Head >= 0` is `[1,2,3] >= 0` which doesn't work.

You need another predicate; an outer one to unpack the lists, another to unpack the integers in each list. This pattern:

```
inner([]).
inner([N|Ns]) :-
    write(N), write(' '),
    inner(Ns).

outer([]).
outer([L|Ls]) :-
    inner(L),
    outer(Ls).
```

e.g.

```
?- X = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 0]],
   outer(X).
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 0
```

I'll leave filling in the details as an exercise for the reader, because it's an exercise.

---

If you just want checks achieved, there are shorter ways:

```
validate(X) :-
    X = [[A,B,C],[D,E,F],[G,H,I]],
    All = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],
    forall(member(N, All), (integer(N),between(0,8,N))),
    sort(All, [_,Second|_]),
    \+ Second = 0.
```

X must unify with that structure of three lists of three items. The variables which are bound must all be integers between 0 and 8. If you sort them and there are more than one 0, the sort will begin `[0,0,...]` so check the second item and if that's a 0 there are too many zeros, so it should not `\+` be a zero.